# Animal sacrifices on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, korban, tetzaveh

Parashat Tetzaveh discusses the various offerings and sacrifices that are to be regularly given. Of these, two animal sacrifices must be enacted every day of the week:

> Thus you shall do to Aaron and his sons, just as I have commanded you. You shall ordain them through seven days, and each day you shall prepare a bull as a purification offering for expiation; you shall purge the altar by performing purification upon it, and you shall anoint it to consecrate it.
>
> Now this is what you shall offer upon the altar: two yearling lambs each day, regularly. You shall offer the one lamb in the morning, and you shall offer the other lamb at twilight. ([Exodus 29:35-39](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.29.35?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

(This is taken from the 1985 JPS translation, which is what I had been working with.) How does this work with the halacha around Shabbat? As far as I can tell, that it is a burnt offering does not matter, as the fire of the altar is never ignited or extinguished, but how about preparing the animal for sacrifice? Isn't butchering a melacha?